# How to use a hash table to find a cycle in a singly linked list?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list, hashtable, cycle

I am aware this is a common question asked, but no answers I've found differ from my algorithm, yet leetcode states my algorithm doesn't work. How can I use a hash table to find if there is a cycle in a singly linked list in JS? I implemented the following algorithm:

```
var hasCycle = function(head) {
    let node = head;
    let table = {};

    while(node) {
        if(table[node.value]) {            
            return true;
        }  
        else {
            table[node.value] = true;
        }
        node = node.next;
    }

    return false;
};
```

However on leetcode, my algorithm works until it hits the following test case:

```
Input: [1, 2], pos: -1
```

Where `[1, 2]` is the linked list, and `pos` is the position of the node that the tail points to. Since it is -1, the tail points to null so there is no cycle.

Why does leetcode say my code returns `true`? In my while loop, the first iteration sets table[1] to true. In the second iteration, table[2] is set to true. Then we exit the while loop since node points to null now, so my code should return false. However, leetcode says my algorithm returns true. Where did I make a mistake?

I am aware of the tortoise and hare algorithm, but I am trying to understand the hash table method to find a cycle.

Comment: I've checked your algorithm with this example `console.log(hasCycle({value : 1 , next : {value:2 , next : null}}));` and it returns false; could you please share your data ? I think the data,which is used as a parameter for function, is different from what you expect

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the exact data used as the parameter for my function, since the test cases and parameters are from leetcode. The only information they provide for the input they used to test my algorithm is `Input: [1, 2], pos: -1`. I'm glad that you also received False running my algorithm as well.

Comment: It's an array of integer and there isn't any next or value. Do you wrap your data into a linked list object?

Comment: In my algorithm, I do not wrap my data into a linked list object. I'm not sure if leetcode wraps their test case data/input data into a linked list object to test my algorithm. Unfortunately, I don't have much information on how their test cases are run to test my algorithm. Could their be a mistake in how they test my algorithm?

Comment: write `console.log(head)` to see the data. I will leave a code in answers section . it works base on array inputes

Comment: I found that this is what they used as the test case `ListNode { val: 1, next: ListNode { val: 2, next: null } }`. So I believe your first console.log test, `console.log(hasCycle({value : 1 , next : {value:2 , next : null}}))` is essentially the same test, as opposed to a test that uses an array.

Comment: I guess this question is the result of a typo: `.value` is not `.val`. I vote to close this question as typo.

Comment: Changing .value is .val passed the test cases. Thank you everyone. For some reason, even with my algorithm using .value, it passed 14/17 test cases before it complained.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you need to do is traverse through the list and see which comes first? The end of the list, or a previously visited node. You can use your Hashtable to record what nodes you have visited, although you really need is a `Set`, but you can use a hashtable for this purpose if that is what the specifications are:

Here's how you go about it:

1. Check if the node you are at is null. If so, there are no cycles
2. Check if the node you are at is already in the hashtable. If so, there is a cycle

If not 1 or 2:

3. Add the node to the hashtable
4. Go on to the next node in the list

Comment: I believe my algorithm matches your specifications. However, leetcode states it does not work with the test case I listed. Would you know why leetcode is saying the algorithm fails with that specific test case? My algorithm passed 14/17 test cases before reaching this test case.

Answer (score 0):

Check this algorithm. It works fine for array

```
var hasCycle = function(data) {
    let dataLength = data.length;
    let table = {};
    for(let i=0 ; i < dataLength; i++ ) {
      if(table[data[i]]) {            
            return i;
        } 
        table[data[i]] = true;
    }
    return -1;
};


console.log(hasCycle([1,2,1]));// 2
console.log(hasCycle([1,2])); // -1
```

Comment: I found that this is what they used as the test case ListNode { val: 1, next: ListNode { val: 2, next: null } }. So it would seem they are in fact using objects as nodes, as opposed to using an array as the test input.